# When viewing an Applet, why does Safari for Windows display "Java is Unavailable or Not Installed" when Java is installed and available?

Tags: windows, safari, applet, java

When using Safari on Windows 7 to load any page containing any Java applet, the following alert appears:

`"Java is Unavailable or Not Installed.  Do you want to go to a page where you can download java?"`

This message is incorrect. These are developer machines with one or more instances of the Java JRE / JDK installed, including 1.7.x.  Many alerts are accompanied by messages referencing a non-existent file path, similar to:

`"The Java Runtime Environment cannot be loaded from
<C:\PROGRA~2\Oracle\JAVAFX~1.1RU\bin\server\jvm.dll>”`

The following attempts to repair the situation have all failed:

- Uninstalling and re-installing various Java versions.
- Updating to the latest Java version.
- Changing security settings in Safari.
- Going to http://www.java.com/en/download/help/testvm.xml detects an obtuse version that is not even installed (Java 2 Runtime Environment, SE v1.4.2_19 ?!?!)

Searching the internet reveals many users with similar problems, but no answers.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While many complaints about this problem exist online, a Google search against *"Safari Windows jvm.dll JAVAFX"* finds [this obscure thread on the Apple Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3192281?start=0&tstart=0).

Summarized, the problem is when Safari checks the Windows Registry for a particular value, it uses the **first** value it finds instead of the **correct** value.

### Steps to repair the issue:

1. Close all Safari windows.
2. Run `regedit.exe`
3. Backup your Windows registry (right-click the root `Computer` and select `export`).
4. Go to

   - 32-bit Windows: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\`
   - 64-bit Windows: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\`
5. Examine each entry; there will probably be more than one.

   - Some entries reference proper JREs, while some may reference JavaFX or something else.
   - The JavaFX one may have been installed by Java 7.
   - It is likely Safari is selecting the bottom-most sorted entry; check whether the file path reference for that entry is invalid or nonexistent.
6. select the bad entry under `..\Java Plug-in\`, cross your fingers, and delete it.
7. close regedit
8. re-open Safari and browse to [a page with an applet](http://java.sun.com/applets/jdk/1.4/demo/applets/Clock/example1.html).  Give it a minute.
9. At this point, you should be successful.  If it continues to fail, check other registry entries under the `..\Java Plug-in\` or parent subfolder `..\JavaSoft\` for invalid file paths.  If you recently upgraded, a prior installation may have been invalidated, but the registry entries might not have been removed, and might have to be excised manually.

**NOTE:** Regarding step 4, your data may be under a different location; check the comments below for the experiences of other users who have resolved this issue in a similar fashion.  **Please post any alternate Windows Registry paths below as a comment.**

*Appreciation goes to user Olivier2011 (Olivier Lefevre) of the Apple Support Community (see first link in this answer) for following up his own question with his solution. [Oliver's historical record of the incident from MarkMail.](http://markmail.org/thread/ofjdxbrnhjntwxkf)*

Comment: First, this worked for me so thanks! But on my 64bit Windows 7 installation the registry key was not located in the referenced path, it was instead located here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in

Comment: It may be different on a per-machine basis.

Comment: i didn't find any registry with \java plug-in ?

Answer (score 2):

Tried above but didn't work.

deleted java related stuff in C:\Program Files (x86)\Safari\Plugins - .jar and dll

Working now.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? My Safari-Java did not work after deleting the Registry Keys; I had to delete this two files, too. Thank you, cheongi!

Comment: Comment from an anonymous user, which I accidentally review: "Finally solved! after so long and so many futile attempts,reading this post! For me the problem was not the reggistry values, but the two java plugin pre-installed with safari, in C/Program Files/Safari/Plugin, deleted those problem solved.Thanks again, this is the only discussion around all web where there is solution!"

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with "java online install".

To solve:

1. Uninstall all JavaFX and JRE in your machine.
2. Download "java offline install" (~=20MB).
3. Copy "java offline install" to Desktop.
4. Close all Safari windows, including the download window.
5. Install java.

Comment: The trick is that you shouldn't need to uninstall all Java installations to handle this problem.  The issue is with a poorly read registry key.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the combination of the top answer, the explanation at: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3192281?start=0&tstart=0 and marcus pope's windows 7 location worked for me.
That is:
I have windows 7.
When trying to run a java applet (geogebra) I got the error message that Safari

> could not load C:\PROGRA~1\Oracle\JAVAFX~1.0\bin\server\jvm.dll

since the path does not exist on my machine. 
This is short for: `C:\Programme\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 1.0\etc` ...

Steps:

1. I shut down Safari.
2. I opened my registry and went to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in`.
3. There I found 2 folders (others have found more). The highest one was 10.5.1 and there I found a reference to the path C:\Programme\Oracle\JavaFX Runtime 1.0\etc.
4. I backed up my registry and then deleted this folder.
5. I restarted Safari and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

You guys may want to look at the code that launches the applet, as it can specify which java version to run the applet in. There is a code that can be specified that says use the latest available. You also have the option to uninstall your java and resinstall it with a earlier version. Some broswers however will force you to use the latest, as there are some security risks with older versions.

Some reference links that might be of help:

- Multibrowser supported applets:
  https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/XHTML/appletObject.html
- Applet Params: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html

Comment: You shouldn't need to uninstall Java installations to handle this problem. The issue is with a poorly read registry key.  This is a client-side problem with Safari; your answer refers to reconfiguring the server-side which hosts the applet, which is not an option.

Comment: @JoshDM, thanks I must of made some bad assumptions when writing my reply :) I read through the other posts and see what you are talking about. I'll leave my response as a reference, even though it doesn't directly apply to the stated question...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with Java after installing Java 7 update 15.

I tried all the above troubleshooting methods, but they all failed (I did not have plugins referred to by the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in.`).

What did work using Safari 5.1.7 was downloading an earlier version of Java (Java 7 update 11) from Oracle directly (the same version I used during the Safari 5.1.7 shelf life, when Safari 6 was Mac only).

The steps are:

1. Uninstall Java from machine.
2. Download "java offline install" (Java 7 update 11) (~=30MB).
3. Copy "java offline install" to Desktop.
4. Close all Safari windows, including the download window.
5. Install Java.

Comment: Java Download: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above methods, and the post by 'Luds' worked.

I did have a plugin referred to by the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in (for Java 7 update 17) 
but after I uninstalled JAVA 7 Update 17 from the windows control panel, it removed this entry.

I tried Java 7 Update 17, 15, 13 with no luck.

What worked for Safari 5.1.7 was downloading an earlier version of Java (Java 7 update 11) from Oracle directly **like the poster 'Luds' mentioned**.

The steps are:

1. Uninstall current Java from machine.
2. Download jre-7u11-windows-x64.exe (Java 7 update 11) (~=30MB) from:
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jre-7u11-oth-JPR
3. Copy the flavor of installer you need to Desktop.
4. Close all open Safari windows,
   including the download window.
5. Install Java SE Runtime Environment 7u11 (Java 7 update 11).